# Can Intel SGX enclaves run at ring 0?

Tags: intel

I gather that SGX enclaves run at ring 3. I want to run a program inside SGX enclave which will want to access kernel data structures and files. Is there any way I could achieve this?

In other words, can we run SGX enclaves using sudo with root privileges?

Comment: root isn't the same thing as ring0.  user-space root processes can only access kernel memory through `/dev/mem` and things like that, and can't run privileged instructions.

Answer (score 1):

SGX Enclaves currently only allow for Ring 3 code execution. 
Intel SGX enclave runs in ring 3 only, no kernel mode. 
Intel SGX objective is secure the application in ring 3 itself.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

The way to want to access kernel data structure maybe through OCALL.
You can call an OCALL inside of the enclave and let the untrusted code/host application call some system call functions to fetch the data you want.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Can you please elaborate what OCALL is?

Comment: @cout_display_name 
It is a basic concept of using SGX. OCALL is when an application inside of enclave calling function out of enclave, and maybe get some information back. And ECALL is when a host application outside of the enclave calling into enclave.

You may want to go through the Intel SGX manual so that you can have better understand of what they are and how to use it. 
https://download.01.org/intel-sgx/linux-1.5/docs/Intel_SGX_SDK_Developer_Reference_Linux_1.5_Open_Source_Beta.pdf